# How can I display an error page for unauthorised access in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, authorization

I'm working on authz in an Angular application. We're using routing heavily, so it seems to make sense to check for authorisation in route guards.

I do this in a `canActivateChild` route, with the setup being roughly like this:

```
class MyGuard implements CanActivateChild {
    canActivateChild(route, state) {
      return !route.data || route.data.active;
    }
}

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    canActivate: [MyGuard],
    canActivateChild: [MyGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'hello', component: HelloComponent, data: { active: false }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

(This is obviously heavily simplified, but the details of how I determine if a route is authorised aren't relevant I think. A more complete working example is on StackBlitz at https://stackblitz.com/edit/dv-so-angular-route-authz)

My problem is that the route guard only lets me do two things when authorization fails: return `false` and have the navigation cancel entirely and stay on the original route; or redirect to a different URL.

The UI I'd like for this is showing an error message, but under the URL the user tried to navigate to. (I.e. in case this is a mistake in setting up rights, it's easier for the user to report "hey I can't access this URL", then reload the page.) Effectively I want the equivalent of a server returning a HTTP 403 status with a body.

I've thought of not doing the check on the route and having the target components themselves display something else. I'm not particularly a fan of this though, if for no other reason that it messes with on-demand loading of modules. Is there a "clean" way to do this from the router?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the response you are waiting for, but I question the very principle. Routing in Angular makes sure that one important invariant is always true: the component used in routing is given through the routing table. That's why you don't find an easy way to do what you planned.

My guess is that diverging from this principle is asking for maintanability and/or reliability issues down the road.

I would see as a solution to your initial desire the following: you route the failing request to `the/initial/path/failed`, and the component for this route contains the error data that could be useful to the IT team.

Then, in the `the/initial/path/failed` route, you put an inverted guard: if rights are ok, then you redirect to `the/initial/path`.

That way, you don't break the Angular invariant at the core of the routing universe.

That's a process similar to rolling back to login page when not logged-in, and skipping the login page if already logged-in.

**Edit**:
I see your points in the comments and I mostly agree with you.
Still, to try and move a solution forward, here is an acceptable no boilerplate approximation:

You create a simple "Fail" component. It shows a message taken from a service (classic inter-component messaging, similar to a flash message capability). In your guard:

```
router.navigate(...).then(_ =>
  Service.post_flash_message('instructions with "retry" link to initial url'));
```

Not exactly your request, but a step toward.

Comment: It’s indeed not the answer I’m looking for. I’m building the app for users, not for framework authors. I’ll need a stronger warning than a vague “this might lead to issues” - every line of code you write *might*. As far as I’m aware, Ng routing doesn’t allow for routes like `**/failed`, so your approach seems like it would involve a lot of boilerplate, which is hardly a maintenance boon.

Comment: I also think the alleged similarity to a user signing in doesn't quite fit. An unauthenticated user may take an action to rectify that - sign in - which is why they're being taken on the detour to the sign-in page and back. For an unauthorized user, there is no action they may take, they're either accessing a resource they're not supposed to, or an administrator must grant him access; they're at a dead end from the start so adding more steps is pointless.

Comment: Ok. Edited my answer with an additional idea if it helps. Although I don't quite agree on framework. When you choose an opiniated framework, you play by the rule or you open up some difficult paths. That's not fact but experience, I agree it is not valid 100% of the time. But I found when I was stuck in such state, there was often an acceptable solution in the framework. You can sure drive from A to B going only backwards, but it's gonna be a hell of a ride :)

Answer (score 1):

Just to add another thought: Have you considered returning a new observable in the guard? Angular guards may either return a `boolean`, or a `Observable<boolean>`. This way, you could delay the actual routing process by showing a modal with your error / warning message before denying the route navigation.

That could be achieved like this:

```
class MyGuard implements CanActivateChild {
    canActivateChild(route, state): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
      if (!route.data || route.data.active) {
        // TODO: return your modal observable here and map it to boolean, e.g. via:
        return modalService.alert('Data error').map(() => false);
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```

I actually used this pattern in my application to allow a user to renew their token / login in the modal (if the guard detects that the token is expired which will most probably lead to a server API error), then proceed with navigation after the new token has been acquired. The guard will "dangle" until the observable emits `true` or `false`.

Comment: What would this do of the user just cold-navigates to an unauthorized URL, say by opening a link in a new tab? We do have a toast notification utility, but I really don’t know if Ng even renders anything. I’ll keep this trick for later, but I have to stress that this is authorization, not authentication. There is nothing for the user to do within the app UI to gain access to the resource, if he’s supposed to have it, an administrator will have to grant him the appropriate role and the user will have to hard-reload to load the new capabilities anyway.